# Add a sign (#!) in beginning of line in a file

Tags: python, bash, file

I have some files where the first three lines is just a header. But for me to read them they need a comment-sign in the beginning like a `#`.
If my file is called `test.txt` (example shown below) how do I add a `#` to only the first three lines, and if possible not add a comment-sign if there already is `#`.

```
A    B    C    D
1    2    3    4

131  4.32  23  42
132  4.31  22  42
...  ...  ... ...
```

After the first three lines I have my actually data. So I would like it to be:

```
#A    B    C    D
#1    2    3    4
#
131  4.32  23  42
132  4.31  22  42
...  ...  ... ...
```

so I can easily load the data with for example `np.loadtxt('test.txt')` in python.
I have the idea it would be easiest in bash but python is okay too.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: read the file with the readlines() in an array. Loop trought the array and put a "#" in front of the first 3 lines. Then write the array out again. solution for python

Comment: it's better to do some research before asking, and ask more precise questions. cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you tagged the question with `bash`, so you could try this sed one-liner in your shell:

```
sed '1,3s/^/#/' file
```

if you want to make the change "in place": add `-i`

```
sed -i '1,3s/^/#/' file
```

**EDIT**

skip the line if there is already leading `#`:

```
sed '1,3{/^#/!s/^/#/}'
```

Comment: I think some previous checking is missing, as the OP says *and if possible not add a comment-sign if there already is #*. `sed '1,3s/^[^!#]/#/ file` could work.

Comment: @fedorqui yep, thx. I didn't see that line. now updated.

Comment: Good one, +1! Let me understand `{/^#/!s/^/#/}`: does it mean if `/^#/` do not `s`, otherwise `s/^/#/`?

Comment: @fedorqui yes, you said it. same as `/foo/!d`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `awk`, this can work:

```
awk '(NR<=3 && !/^#/) {$0="#"$0} {print}' your_file
```

#### Explanation

`(NR<=3 && !/^#/)` stands for number of line <= 3 and lines not starting with `#`. In that case, we update the line with leading `#` with `$0="#"$0`. If condition is not matched, we just print the line with `{print}`.

#### Tests

Without any `#`:

```
$ cat s
A    B    C    D
1    2    3    4

131  4.32  23  42
132  4.31  22  42

$ awk '(NR<=3 && !/^#/) {$0="#"$0} {print}' s
#A    B    C    D
#1    2    3    4
#
131  4.32  23  42
132  4.31  22  42
```

Already with some `#`:

```
$ cat s
#A    B  #  C    D
1    2    3    4

131  4.32  23  42
132  4.31  22  42

$ awk '(NR<=3 && !/^#/) {$0="#"$0} {print}' s
#A    B  #  C    D
#1    2    3    4
#
131  4.32  23  42
132  4.31  22  42
```